# MCQ: Finding the interval in which the least positive root of the equation $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2^k x)}{2^k}=0$ lies.

Tags: trigonometry, summation, numerical-methods, approximation

This problem is to be solved within $3$ minutes, without a calculator.

[image]

My approach is bad:

The least positive solution of $\sin(x)=0$ is $\pi$,

The least positive solution of $\sin(x)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)=0$ is "slightly" less then $\pi$,

When $k$ is "large", the terms approaches $0$. So I choose option (E). In fact, it is the correct answer.

I think a numerical method is to be used. I do not know how.

---

The word "slightly" and the word "large" are not technical here.

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know complex numbers?

Comment: Your claim about the first two terms is wrong, $\sin(x)(1+\cos(x))$ has the first positive root still at $x=\pi$, now even a triple root.

Comment: @user58697 yes I do, then?

Comment: @lutzlehmann sir clarify what is wrong, please. Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing "slightly less" for the first positive root of that expression.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that you look at the non trivial positive solutions ($0$ and $\pi$)  $x_n$ of the equation
$$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{\sin(2^k x)}{2^k}=0$$

For $n=2$ (for $n<2$, only trivial roots)
$$S_2=\sin (x)+\frac{1}{2} \sin (2 x)+\frac{1}{4} \sin (4 x)=\sin (x) \left(2 \cos ^3(x)+1\right)\implies x_2=\cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)$$ This is the lower bound of all $x_n$. In other words
$$\frac {4}5 \pi < x_n < \pi $$ So, option $(E)$ is the correct one.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Can you clarify how did you evaluate $x_2=(-\frac{1}{2^\frac{1}{3}})$ and say this is the lower bound of "all" $x_n$? Thanks.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari. You misread. $ \left(2 \cos ^3(x)+1\right)=0\implies x_2=\cos ^{-1}\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}}\right)$. Now, what happens when you add the next term ?